# TCP client keep sending to itself

Tags: c++, tcp

I am making a very simple TCP client-server connection. When I launch the server (in a ROS2 node, WSL2 Ubuntu 20) and then the client for the first time everything work. Then when I kill the server try to do it again the client sends the data to ... somewhere, I have no idea.

I restarted the computer (Win 11) and only start the client it always connects to itself ! (see the screenshot)

Why is that ?! and What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
#include <direct.h>


#define BUF_SIZE 29
char IP_addr[15 + 1] = "127.0.0.1";
int portno = 50000;


int main() {

    //SET UP THE TCP CLIENT CONNECTION
    struct sockaddr client;
    socklen_t client_size = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET client_sock_no = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (client_sock_no == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Cannot create the soscket";
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        struct sockaddr_in client_sock_addr;
        client_sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        inet_pton(AF_INET, IP_addr, &client_sock_addr.sin_addr);
        client_sock_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

        int bindStatus = bind(client_sock_no, (struct sockaddr*)&client_sock_addr, sizeof(client_sock_addr));
        std::cerr << "Binding the socket to the client...\n";

        if (bindStatus != 0) {
            std::cerr << "...Cannot bind (error " << bindStatus << ")\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "The TCP client has been set up !\n";
            //connect to server
            int connect_status = connect(client_sock_no, (sockaddr*)&client_sock_addr, sizeof(client_sock_addr));
            if (connect_status != 0) {
                std::cerr << "Cannot connect (status " << connect_status << " ; error " << errno << ")\n";
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Connected (status " << connect_status << ")\n";
                char data[BUF_SIZE] = "-199.5;-299.5;-399.5;-499.5;";
                data[BUF_SIZE - 1] = '\0';
                size_t n;

                for (int k = 0; k <= 10; k++) {
                    send(client_sock_no, data, BUF_SIZE, MSG_DONTROUTE);
                    std::cout << data << std::endl;
                }
            }

        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

[Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru2BN.png)

Comment: You called `bind` on the socket, so it is both a server and client... A client just have to connect. See this for example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/

Comment: Well, I clearly misunderstood something. I have no idea why it worked at first then. Anyway, thanks it works great now!

Comment: As written either the bind or the connect will fail -- the bind will fail if there's already a server listening on the socket, and the connect will fail if there's not a server listening on the socket.